# After Angular 15 upgrade - bundle-dependencies unknown parameter error

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular15

After upgrading from angular 13 to 15, the command `ng run Web:server:production --bundle-dependencies true` is failing. Getting the following error: Error: Unknown argument: bundle-dependencies

We need to know what can be done such that the command executes successfully. TIA.

Answer (score 1):

This was removed in Angular 15 you can check it here [Angular CLI](https://github.com/alan-agius4/angular-cli/commit/84096725bc37882d029e3c88a1bbc2a00660f4e7)

> BREAKING CHANGE: The server builder `bundleDependencies` option has
> been removed. This option was used pre Ivy. Currently, using this
> option is unlikely to produce working server bundles.
>
> The `externalDependencies` option can be used instead to exclude
> specific node_module packages from the final bundle.